# .htaccess hide directory in url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have search here but couldn't find the answer to my specific question..maybe im too noob to figure it out and i'm sorry :(

so what i need is I have a domain: http://www.mydomain.com
and I have a directory which is: http://www.mydomain.com/directory

in my main domain www.mydomain.com/index.php file i have a script which detects the country and forwards to http://www.mydomain.com/directory

but i want to hide that "directory" so even if i redirect via script i want the url to stay at
http://www.mydomain.com

is this possible?

Edit: I am using [Maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com/en/lookup?pkit_lang=en) Geolocation to do the redirect, no querystrings. So it'll detect and forward on to the directory, but I would like the url to remain the same.

Comment: So basically you don't want to redirect at all? :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could setup some cookies with php and then use HTTP_COOKIE with mod_rewrite, but not with .htaccess alone.

Example with .htaccess cookie:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} lang=([^;]*)
RewriteRule .* $0?lang=%1 [L,QSA,NS]
```

Comment: i just edited my question, there's no querystrings being used here.  Just a geolocation to determine where the user is sent to.